# Colimit of spaces of sections of structure sheaf over all Zariski open subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits, zariski-topology

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety, say over algebraically closed field $k$, $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ its's structure sheaf. Denote also $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ the irreducible components of $X$. 
Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the category of all Zariski dense open subsets of $X$ with inclusions as morphisms. Is it true that this category is cofiltered ? I define cofiltered category $C$ as a one satisfying the following two axioms: 
1) for any objects $a,b$ there exist an object $c$ and a couple of morphisms  $c\rightarrow a$ $c\rightarrow b$
2) for two parallel morphisms $f: a\rightarrow b$ , $g:a\rightarrow b$ there exists a morphism $h:c\rightarrow a$ such that $fh=gh$.

Note that if the category of Zariski open subsets is cofiltered, than the set of vector spaces $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ has a structure of filtered diagram in the category of vector spaces. What would be the $colim _{U} \mathcal{O}_{X}(U\in \mathcal{U})$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The first axiom follows from the fact that an open subset is dense iff it is dense in each $X_n$, so an intersection of two dense open subsets is dense and you can take $c=a\cap b$.  The second axiom is automatic since there is only one morphism between any two objects in this category.

To compute your colimit, note that the set $\bigcup_i \left(X_i\setminus \bigcup_{j\neq i} X_j\right)$ of all points that are only contained in one component is an open dense subset, so we may assume the $X_n$ are disjoint.  We then have $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\prod_i\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap X_i)$ for each $i$, and we can take the colimit on each coordinate separately.  But the colimit on the $i$th coordinate is just the the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_{X_i}$ at the generic point of $X_i$, also known as the function field $K(X_i)$, so your colimit is $\prod_i K(X_i)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain more about why the set of points that are contained in only one component $X_{i}$ is dense open ? As long as I understand as a set it is the $X_{I}\ - \cap _{j=1} ^{n} X_{j}$ and it is definitely not dense in Zariski topology.

Comment: The "one component" I referred to isn't fixed.  So I meant $\bigcup_i \left(X_i\setminus \bigcup_{j\neq i} X_j\right)$.  This is dense in each $X_i$ and hence in $X$.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. Can you also explain how to calculate $colim \mathcal{O}_{X}(U\cap X_{i})$ for irreducible component $X_{i}$? I think you assumed in your calculation that $X$ was affine , so $X_{i}$ is the zero set of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset K[X]$, where $K[X]=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$.

Comment: In this case $K[X]/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain and it's zero ideal is the common point $x_{0}$ of $X_{i}$. So the colimit is actually taken over all $U \cap X_{i}$ containing $x_{0}$

Comment: So the intersection of all $U\cap X_{i}$ is $x_{0}$ and the colimit is $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_{0}}=K(X_{i})$.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to explain it.  You don't have to assume anything is affine though--if $x_0$ is the generic point of $X_i$, then the colimit on the $i$th coordinate will by definition be the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X_i,x_0}$, which is by definition the function field $K(X_i)$.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you.